# React Native: Axios network error using get request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, axios

In react native application, the backend returns a simple json and I want to use it with axios on the client side, but it gives an error that I have never seen.

[react native app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05KGg.jpg)

[express js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK9RD.jpg)

it works when i use a different api

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => setData(res.data[0]));
  }, []);

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome {data.name}!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
```

Then i will get this.
`[AxiosError: Network Error]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had similiar issue before with `React-Native` when running on `Android Emulator`
**solution** for me was changing the api url from `http://localhost:5000/` to `http://10.0.2.2:5000/`

Comment: @AliyasirNaç can you please let me know how you resolve the error?

Comment: Hey @AliyasirNaç. Happy you solved it :). `React-Native` does work with `localhost`, It is the `Android Emulator` that is requiring different `Network Configurations` to be able to connect to. For more see "Android Developers Documentations"[link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)

Comment: @VishalDhanotiya i used  my ipv4 address and it will work

Comment: i also facing same issue in my react native application with physical device (my mobile phone) can you provide some solution??

Answer (score 0):

your request api is worked in postman?
checked your conection , url address and url port..

the best way for get the correct url is postman.

https or http ?
and test your url in  '  '

Answer (score -1):

Your Express app needs to use CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). Add the following to your server file:

```js
var app = express();

// ADD THIS
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```